# Splitting code to files

Tags: bash, terminal, vim, c++, g++

I`m writing long c++ code using vim editor and I compile using bash terminal
I want to organize my code by writing functions in separate files
can I write a function in new sub-file and attach all sub-files to a main file.cpp ?

Comment: like that `g++ file.cpp file1.cpp main.cpp ...`?

Comment: This question will better fit in StackOverflow, but yes, you can: you must declare your functions on a header file and include this header file on your main.cpp, then use a command line like the one suggested by @Arkadiusz Drabczyk

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash, vim, or a terminal and everything to do with understanding how to compile c++